# TMG returns uncompressed content response from IIS

Tags: iis, microsoft-ftmg-2010, tmg

I'm fighting with my customer's TMG for a few days already and I'm out of ideas. I hope you can help me.

As I understand it TMG is set as a proxy between Internet and local computer with IIS with my application on it. I need to configure it to pass compressed content from IIS to Internet.

What we already did:
1. We set SendAcceptEncodingHeader to True, so that Content-Encoding is passed to IIS,
2. We enabled Compression Filter. We added computer on Return Compressed Data and Request Compressed Data tabs on Http Compression properties window. I also selected all mime types on Compressible content types.

I noticed that after changes IIS receives Content-Encoding in header and sends compressed content. The problem is that TMG removes compression and client receives content without compression. Could you please help me find solution to that problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Return Compressed Data" tab, it sounds like you've added the backend server (IIS).

This will never work, you need to add the Web Listener that the clients are requesting the content through.

Comment: That works, thank you! However only some of the content is compressed. Do you maybe know if I can disable TMG compression filter just for that single page so that entire compression is performed on IIS and TMG just passing compressed data?

Comment: Sounds more like you might be hitting the FrequentHitThreshold in IIS, unless you can see the content being compressed before it's returned. If it is, then it's possible TMG has cached the compressed content already, so try using a cache rule which always requests content, and see if it behaves any differently. If it does, the CacheDir tool used to be the way to clear that out, but I noticed a forum post that mentioned the Firewall service might need to be stopped for it to see the cache these days. YMMV.